# How to analyze change detection using Earth Engine and Python?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat

Bellow there is an area which has been classified (legend is on bottom right). What is the code in order to get how many pixels are corresponding to each class? For example, 3000 pixels correspond to class where NDVI is 0-0,2, 1000 pixels correspond to class where NDVI is above 0,6. I would like to do it in order to get a change percentage over time for different NDVI images.

Bellow there is Earth Engine's code with its link:

**https://code.earthengine.google.com/ac259b5408e44674e6df56dadcea6250**

```
 var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA') var image = ee.Image( landsat.filterBounds(geometry) .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-8-31') .median() ); // 1. Clip the image in a specified boundary. var composite = image.clip(geometry); var composite = composite.toFloat() // Add map layers Map.addLayer(composite , {bands: ['B6', 'B5', 'B4']}, "composite", false); // 2. Compute the NDVI var nir = image.select('B5'); var red = image.select('B4'); var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)); var ndvi = ndvi.clip(geometry); // Add map layers Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['black', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'continuous NDVI',false); // Compute the mean and stdev of NDVI var mean_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegion({ reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geometry, scale: 30 }); var sd_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegion({ reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(), geometry: geometry, scale: 30 }); print(mean_ndvi); print(sd_ndvi); // 3. Classify NDVI into 5 classes var ndvi2 = ee.Image(1) .where(ndvi.gt(0.0).and(ndvi.lte(0.2)), 2) .where(ndvi.gt(0.2).and(ndvi.lte(0.4)), 3) .where(ndvi.gt(0.4).and(ndvi.lte(0.6)), 4) .where(ndvi.gt(0.6), 5) var ndvi2 = ndvi2.clip(geometry); // Add map layers Map.addLayer(ndvi2, {min: 1, max: 5, palette: ['#654321','#FFA500','#FFFF00', '#00FF00', '#008000']}, 'Classified NDVI',true); // Add map title var mapTitle = ui.Panel({ style: { position: 'top-center', padding: '8px 15px' } }); var mapTitle2 = ui.Label({ value: 'Map of NDVI', style: { fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '20px', margin: '0 0 3px 0', padding: '0' } }); mapTitle.add(mapTitle2); Map.add(mapTitle); // Add map legend var legend = ui.Panel({ style: { position: 'bottom-right', padding: '8px 15px' } }); var legend2 = ui.Label({ value: 'Legend (NDVI)', style: { fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '18px', margin: '0 0 4px 0', padding: '0' } }); legend.add(legend2); // Creates the content of the legend var content = function(color, label) { // Create the color boxes var box = ui.Label({ style: { backgroundColor: '#' + color, // Set box height and width padding: '9px', margin: '0 0 4px 0' } }); // Create the labels var labels = ui.Label({ value: label, style: {margin: '0 0 4px 6px'} }); return ui.Panel({ widgets: [box, labels], layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal') }); }; //  Set legend colors var classcolor = ['654321','FFA500','FFFF00', '00FF00', '008000']; // Set legend labels var labelName = ['<=0','0 - 0.2','0.2 - 0.4','0.4 - 0.6', '>0.6']; // Combine legend colou and labels for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { legend.add(content(classcolor[i], labelName[i])); } // Add legend Map.add(legend);
```

[image]

Comment: Not really an answer, but see https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/nclinton/Change_Detection_EEUS2018.  Also note that you should use Landsat Collection 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduceRegion()` with a count reducer, grouping the count by the class.

```
var counts = ndvi2
  // You need two bands when grouping the pixel count per class
  // One for the groups, second to apply the reducer too.
  .addBands(ndvi2) 
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count().group(),
    geometry: geometry, 
    scale: 30, // The count will depend on your scale
    maxPixels: 1e9
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/787dde4792ff7d6fb3f067a21c862685